# prevent insertion if regular expression is not met

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, database-trigger

I am studying triggers statements in MySQL and I need to prevent an insertion if the person's name has special characters.

I thought of doing something like this:

```
create trigger verifydata
    before insert
    on person
    for each row
    begin
        if(not new.name RLIKE '[A-Za-z]') then
            signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'Verify name';
        end if;
    end;@
    delimiter ;
```

But it does not work.

What is the correct way to do it, any recommendations?

Comment: The above code is working fine. But when I am trying to insert bulk, for example, I want to insert 3 rows. If 2 rows are valid and 1 row invalid, 2 rows will be inserted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most recent versions of MySQL support `check` constraints:

```
alter table person add constraint ck_person_name
    check (name not regexp '[^A-Za-z]');
```

Then in most versions still in use, you can emulate it by creating a view:

```
create view v_person as
     select p.*
     from person p
     where p.name not regexp '[^A-Za-z]';
```

Then insert into the view.  If the view logic filters out the insert, then the insert fails.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if your value contains only non-alphabetic characters, while you want to make sure it does not contain any. You need to reverse the logic here:

```
create trigger verifydata
before insert
on person
for each row
begin
    if(new.name rlike '[^A-Za-z]') then
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'Verify name';
    end if;
end;
delimiter ;
```

Note that if you are running MySQL 8.0.16 or higher, you can do this with a check constraint instead of a trigger:

```
alter table person add constraint check_person_name
check (name not rlike '[^A-Za-z]');
```